# Send data from servlet to android application

Tags: android, servlets, servlet-filters

How to send data from servlet to android application?
Suppose user has entered username and password from android application and successfully logged in to server.
Now without querying another HTTP request from android app I want server to send data to android application during the logged in session. Is this possible?
If yes how to achieve this?
Awaiting for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Google Could Messaging -

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html
```

Comment: @ Mukesh GCM will send data to all users who has that android application that too can send very limited data. Here my requirement is different i have application server user from android app logged into server now during that session i want server to send data to that user without invoking another request.

Comment: You can use GCM to notify the app that it needs to contact the server for some purpose. That way, your app need not know when to initiate a conversation but is controlled by the server.

Comment: @ Mukesh is GCM offers service to send data to only one specific user? Not all who are registered.

Comment: yes you can. See the code snippet here - https://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html